Основы JS, логические операторы
изучая основы JavaScript в разделе логические операторы меня поставил в ступор ответ на данную задачу:
Что выведет код ниже?
alert( alert(1) || 2 || alert(3) );
Ответ: сначала 1, потом 2
Поясните пожалуйста почему оператор ИЛИ который выводит первое истинное значение почему то выводит два значения ?

А почему вы решили, что alert(1) вернет истинное значение ну или вообще что либо?

ИЛИ вообще ничего не выводит. Выводит alert.
